# How to edit multiple files from multiple remote servers in MacVim?

Tags: vim, ftp, ssh, macvim, scp

What's the best way to edit multiple files from multiple remote sources in MacVim? Changes should be saved live to the server. And it would be nice if you could yank and paste changes between multiple files from multiple remote via buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `:e ftp://[user@]machine/path` and `:w ftp://[user@]machine/path` in multiple buffers but it looks to me like an horribly convoluted waste of time.

Try `:help netrw-nread` for more info.

Comment: Guess it would be easier to leave the file handling to an FTP client like Transmit.

Comment: @trnsfmr my thoughts, exactly, though I'd choose YummyFTP instead. Using an FTP client will not solve your "yank & paste betwwen buffers" problem but you can add `set clipboard+=unnamed` to your .vimrc to have Vim's and the system's clipboards "synchronised".

Comment: Indeed, the yank and paste drawback is annoying. Will try your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: I just found an awesome option in MacVim preferences called **Open files from applications**, if you set this to **and set the arglist** MacVim will open files from Transmit into the buffers!

Answer (score 0):

I use Interarchy for FTP, and it handles this quite nicely.  When viewing a remote listing, right click and select "Edit With".  Interarchy sends it to MacVim and handles the buffer automatically.